# Use locator to manage multiple view-viewmodel pairs in Panorama Page

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I'm new to Silverlight/MVVM. I tried some example of MVVM Light, it looks great.

For my scenario, I want to create a Panorama Page, for each Panorama Item, showing my usercontrol, a item list for a customer.

I've built usercontrol(view), viewmodel and WCF service model and works well in a single Panorama Item(Only use first customer).
Also, I use Locator of MVVM Light shown in MIX10 demo, it enables me to make design time data for Expression Blend.

My viewmodel will receive a parameter of customer ID then exchange data with WCF based on this ID.
And the customer list also comes from WCF. So I can't actually makes viewmodels in Locator's static constructor.

If viewmodels are built in runtime by calling Locator, how to make data binding?

The only way I think about is to make viewmodel object in usercontrol's constructor and make it datacontext.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same declarative model in the XAML, you can put a CurrentCustomerViewModel property on the locator and then set property to the right viewmodel before you navigate to the page.

Personally though for pages like that I typically put a viewmodel factory method on the locator (so it can cache them, etc) and call it from the OnNavigatedTo method, something like this.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string id = NavigationContext.QueryString["customerID"];
    vm = ViewModelLocator.GetCustomerViewModel(id);
    DataContext = vm;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Then I just use Blend's sample data capabilities for design time data. This way also helps support pinning the page to the start screen since that will be the entry point to the app and I won't necessarily get a good chance to set the "CurrentCustomerVM" property anyway.